# How to take screenshots of a part of the screen that I've selected, every few seconds (Windows or Linux)

Tags: windows, screenshot

As the title says, how can I take screenshots of a particular part of the screen (like drag to select the area of the screenshot in the Windows Snipping Tool) and have it keep screenshotting every x amount of seconds and saving them to a chosen destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Irfanview. It's free for personal use. If it is running Press C or use menu bar -> options -> Capture/Screenshot... for screenshots.

There are many different ways to choose captured area like full desktop, foreground window or fixed screen.
You choose custom hotkey or timed screenshots. You can use a dedicated folder or your last used printer.

If you are an advanced user, you can use its command line options to write a script.

There are many different applications for Linux like GIMP or built-in in every Linux desktop environment. Just press printscreen for a screenshot.